# Django and chart.js - one bar per 'date' in model

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I have a model that contains a date and a number. There are multiple inputs from the same date that I want to merge into 1 bar on the chart. How can I show each date only once but add up all of the totalPacks under that date?

model: [image]

Views:

```
def homepage(request):
    labels = []
    data = []

    queryset = DailyCountsModel.objects.order_by('-date')
    for jobs in queryset:
        labels.append(jobs.date)
        data.append(jobs.totalPacks)    

    return render(request,'index.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

Currently this chart will show one bar per entry.. I can't think of how I could do this. Any ideas? I'm guessing somehow I would need to check to see how many items they are with the 'date' of 2021-08-23 and add up the 'totalPacks', I'm just not sure how I would do this

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count
result = (DailyCountsModel.objects
    .values('totalPacks', 'date')
    .annotate(dcount=Count('totalPacks'))
    .order_by('-date')
)
```

Comment: How would I use this?

Comment: @uniqueusername42o this query will give what you want.

Comment: When I print this query I get

 {'totalPacks': int, 'dcount': 1}

Why are all of the dcounts 1? I don't think I explained properly. I would need to add together all 'totalPacks' that come under the same 'date', so in my chart I have 1 bar per date with the totalPack count from that date.